# Pandas Function returning "None" instead of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Pandas function is returning "None" as a result instead of the DataFrame that I am trying to filter using the function that I have written. Why is this so? And how can I resolve this? Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
nz_data = pd.read_csv('research-and-development-survey-2016-2019-csv.csv', index_col = 2)

def count_of_mining_biz():
    if "B_Mining" in nz_data[["Breakdown_category"]] and "Count of businesses" in nz_data[["Units"]]:
        return nz_data.loc["2019", "RD_Value"]

print(count_of_mining_biz())
```

[Here is how the data looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHDfF.png)

I am trying to find out the RD Value in 2019 for the Mining industry. The reason why I have to set a conditional for the "Units" column is because there is another type of data that is not the count for the business mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.loc[..., ...]` means `.loc[row_index, col_index]` but there's no row index called `2019`.

Try using `.loc` with boolean masks in this case:

```py
def count_of_mining_biz():
    category = nz_data['Breakdown_category'] == 'B_Mining'
    units = nz_data['Units'] == 'Count of businesses'
    year = nz_data['Year'] == 2019
    return nz_data.loc[category & units & year].RD_Value
```

Comment: Hi Geof, thank you for your help! I encountered an error that says: KeyError: 'Year'. How can I resolve it?

Comment: @pleepc can you copy-paste the output of `print(nz_data.columns)`

Comment: hey Geof, here's the output: Index(['Variable', 'Breakdown_category', 'RD_Value', 'Units'], dtype='object'). However, even after I removed "Year" as my index_col, the output of print(count_of_mining_biz()) gives me: Series([], Name: RD_Value, dtype: object). Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @pleepc (1) If `Year` is a `str` instead of `int`, it needs quotes like `'2019'` instead of just `2019`, so check the output of `print(type(df.iloc[0].Year))` to see which it is. (2) `Units` and `Breakdown_category` might have leading/trailing spaces, so `strip()` them first just in case (and if `Year` ends up being a `str`, then `strip()` it too): `nz_data['Units'] = nz_data['Units'].str.strip(); nz_data['Breakdown_category'] = nz_data['Breakdown_category'].str.strip()`

Comment: hey Geof, thank you so much, it works now after I removed the 'index_col = 2' argument. I managed to get the correct answer, which is '3', however, python returns me another number before that, so I am getting '5   3'. Do you mind explaining why does it have the '5' in front?

Comment: @pleepc That means there are actually two rows satisfying those conditions, one with `RD_Value=5` and another with `RD_Value=3`. To see which rows, you can change the function's last line to return the index instead:     `return nz_data.loc[category & units & year].index`

Comment: Got it, thank you so much Geof for the advices :)